# Multiple if condition with single else in verilog

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, verilog

i have some prblm while checking the conditions using if statement in verilog code. it also similar to c. but in my coding it compares many strings using multiple if . it check if true the condition below the if statement will work. in case if more strings are matched it execute all the true blocks.if there is no match it goes to else...so is any possible in verilog for multiple if with single else....here we not able to use case because the condition is comparision.

Comment: Show some code that u have tried.

Comment: Doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Answer (score 2):

Cascaded if statements:

```
 always @* begin
   if ( ... ) begin
     // ...
   end
   else if ( ... ) begin
     // ...
   end
   else begin
     // ...
   end
 end
```

Often the case statement is a better approach:

```
always @* begin
  case ( reg_or_wire )
    0 : begin
      // ...
    end
    1 : begin
      // ...
    end
    default : begin
      // ...
    end
  endcase
end
```

The case values are integer by default but you should probably specify width and value, e.g. 4'b1010, 4'ha;